# Clicking on Named Link in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium

Iam new to selenium web driver.
I have this web application page where it has Links present in a table format, but only the links present in first coloumn are enabled and the rest are disabled.
I have to click on the link present in the first coloumn based on the value present in another coloumn.
example:
**prod name**        **product-id**    **serial#**
    ABC                  xyz             123456
    DEF                  xyz             789012
    ABC                  xyz             999999
    DEF                  xyz             111111

So, based on serial number I want to click the link which is under product name.

Could someone help me please.

Comment: your going to have to provide an sample of the html really to get any worthwhile help.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the complete html for the above:

Comment: <table id="deviceSearchDataTable" class="word_wrap dataTable" view="deviceSearchView" aria-describedby="deviceSearchDataTable_info">
<colgroup><thead><tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">
<td class=""><a href="/customerdevice/secure/deviceDetail/341052?version=1430232724535">4402TDFUT1StatsBridgeDev7.bng.hp.com</a></td>
<td class="">QR482A</td><td class="">4402SN1007</td><td class="">Dev Ops Company</td><td class="">US</td><td class="">true</td><td class=""/>
</tr>

Comment: i Tried the simple one like :

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("4402TDFUT1StatsBridgeDev7.bng.hp.com")).click();. But still showing me error no such element.

Answer (score 1):

You could try XPATH to get the td with the a you need.
Getting a node with a specific sibling should look like this:

```
/td[1][../td[4]/text() = "your serial"]/a
```

Comment: Showing me the following error :   Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.90) .  same in IE as well

Comment: My XPATH is not your solution it is just an example to show you the way. Try an XPATH-Tester on the web to get the XPATH that finds your element.